# Can't build android apk when using Facebook SDK Unity3D

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I have:
- Unity 4.3
- Setup the Facebook SDK settings
- OpenSSL and Java and JDK etc
- Android SDK Manager rev 21

I have tried:
- Facebook SDK 4.2.4, 4.3.6, 5.0.4
- All the Environmental variables for Android etc ( mind you I can build android for other projects )

I get the following error when I try to build:

Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-17\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Unity3D\xxx\xxx\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding ascii "com\facebook\android\R.java" "com\TerahardLtd\SquashGame\R.java"', CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Unity3D\xxx\xxx\Temp\StagingArea\gen'

One thing I noticed but I don't know if it matters or not is that "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-17\android.jar" -d  has a "\" in the last section of a the path

Comment: hey did u find any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the JDK, not the JRE. This is not documented unfortunately.

Comment: But the problem says it's in the jre7 folder and also I have downloaded the JDK, added it to the path and still I'm getting the same problem

Comment: Ah, yeah, forgot about that. The only way I was able to get this to work was by uninstalling the JRE. Give that a shot?

Comment: (sorry missed the question is from 2014)
It is actually documented:
https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements
You should have the JDK path set in the Editor settings.